# Spring Batch Remote Partitioning - Sometimes Master Step completes before all partition step completes

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have encountered an issue with Spring Batch Remote Partitioning jobs where the master step completes before all partition (slave) step completes. This happens randomly (most of the time the master step finishes after all partition step completes).
Please let me know if I am missing anything in my configuration.

**Here is the Master Job configuration**

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel requestsChannel;

@Autowired
private PollableChannel aggregatedReplyChannel;

@Bean
public JobExecutionListener listener() {
    return new RadJobExecutionListener();
}

@Bean
public Job RadItemProcessingJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("radItemProcessingJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener())
            .start(processRadItems_master()).next(updateSetStatusStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Tasklet noopTaskLet() {
    return new NoopTasklet();
}

@Bean
public Tasklet updateSetStatusStepTasklet() {
    return new UpdateSetStatus();
}

@Bean
public Step processRadItems() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processRadItems")
            .tasklet(noopTaskLet())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Partitioner moduloPartitioner() {
    return new ModuloPartitioner();
}

@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
    return createPartitionHandler("processRadItems",
            gridSize,
            requestsChannel,
            aggregatedReplyChannel
    );
}


public PartitionHandler createPartitionHandler(String stepName,
                                               int gridSize,
                                               MessageChannel requestChannel,
                                               PollableChannel replyChannel) {
    MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new MessageChannelPartitionHandler();
    partitionHandler.setStepName(stepName);
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(gridSize);
    partitionHandler.setReplyChannel(replyChannel);
    MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(requestChannel);
    partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(messagingTemplate);
    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean Step processRadItems_master() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processRadItems.master")
            .partitioner("processRadItem",moduloPartitioner())
            .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
            .build();
}


@Bean Step updateSetStatusStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("updateSetStatusStep")
            .tasklet(updateSetStatusStepTasklet())
            .build();
}

@Bean
JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return simpleJobLauncher;

}
```

**Master JMS Configuration:**

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.url}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${activemq.userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="requestsChannel"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                  channel="requestsChannel"
                                  destination-name="${activemq.requestQueue}"/>

<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                        channel="replyChannel"
                                        destination-name="${activemq.replyQueue}"/>

<int:channel id="aggregatedReplyChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:aggregator ref="partitionHandler"
                input-channel="replyChannel"
                output-channel="aggregatedReplyChannel"
                send-timeout="86420000"/>
```

**Slave - Job Configuration:**

```
@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private DataSource raddAppDataSource;

@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Bean
public Step processRadItems() {
    final TaskletStep step = stepBuilderFactory.get("processRadItems")
            .<RadItem,RadItem>chunk(1)
            .reader(pagingItemReader(null,null,null))
            .processor(itemProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
    step.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    step.setStepExecutionListeners(new StepExecutionListener[]{radStepListener()});
    return step;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public RadItemProcessorJob itemProcessor() {
    return new RadItemProcessorJob();
}

@Bean
public NoOpItemWriter itemWriter() {
    return new NoOpItemWriter();
}

@Bean
public RadStepListener radStepListener() {
    return new RadStepListener();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcPagingItemReader pagingItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['mod.divisor']}") Object modDivisor,
                                             @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['mod.remainder']}") Object modRemainder,
                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['setId']}") Long setId) {
    final JdbcPagingItemReader pagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader();
    pagingItemReader.setDataSource(raddAppDataSource);
    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    sqlFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select rad_item_id, item_oid,coverage_start_date, coverage_end_date, item_status_code, rad_set_id, reprocess_type");
    sqlFactoryBean.setFromClause("from rad_item");
    sqlFactoryBean.setWhereClause("where rad_set_id = :setId and item_status_code in ('SELECTED','PROCESSED','REVIEWING') and mod(rad_item_id, :modDivisor) = :modRemainder");
    sqlFactoryBean.setSortKey("rad_item_id");
    sqlFactoryBean.setDataSource(raddAppDataSource);
    try {
        pagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(sqlFactoryBean.getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating pagingItemReader",e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    initParameterValues(pagingItemReader, modDivisor, modRemainder, setId);

    pagingItemReader.setPageSize(1);
    pagingItemReader.setRowMapper(new RadItemRowMapper());
    return pagingItemReader;
}

private void initParameterValues(JdbcPagingItemReader pagingItemReader, Object modDivisor, Object modRemainder, Long setId) {
    final Map<String,Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
    parameterValues.put("modDivisor",modDivisor);
    parameterValues.put("modRemainder",modRemainder);
    parameterValues.put("setId",setId);
    pagingItemReader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
}

@Bean
public StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler() {
    final StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler =  new StepExecutionRequestHandler();
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer());
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setStepLocator(stepLocator());
    return stepExecutionRequestHandler;
}

@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer() {
    try {
        final JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactory.setDataSource(raddAppDataSource);
        jobExplorerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating JobExplorer Bean",e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Bean
public StepLocator stepLocator() {
    return new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
}
```

**Slave JMS Config:**

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.url}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${activemq.userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
</bean>
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                        destination-name="${activemq.requestQueue}"
                                        channel="requestChannel"/>

<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                  destination-name="${activemq.replyQueue}"
                                  channel="replyChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel"
                       output-channel="replyChannel"
                       ref="stepExecutionRequestHandler"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The Issue is - many times (not always)  the master step completes before all the partition (slave) step completes. This causes issue for my next step.

Comment: Your premise makes no sense; with your configuration, the partition handler should wait forever until the aggregator submits the aggregated replies to the `replyChannel`. There is no receive timeout on the `aggregatedReplyChannel `. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and watch the message flows.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your suggestion. My master configuration had an error and I have updated it (removed the auto-start="false" property of the message driven channel adapter).

Comment: Another issue I have encountered is sometimes only few slaves executing slave steps while there are still steps to finish and idle slave process are available. Appreciate your thoughts on this as well.

Comment: If I add the property auto-start="false" on the message-driven-channel-adapter on the slave jms config, the program immediately exiting on startup. Could someone please explain what am I missing?